# Date format conversion from "yyyy-mm-dd" to "dd/mm/yyyy" in pentaho using javascript

Tags: javascript, pentaho, kettle, date-conversion, pentaho-spoon

I have a csv file where the date field has a format "yyyy-mm-dd" and I wish to convert it into "dd/mm/yyyy" using javascript. This is the javascript it found out from this [reference](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?59838-Modified-JavaScript-str2date)

```
"could not apply the given format yyyy/mm/dd on the string for 2015-02-04 :Format.parseObject(String) failed(script#3)"
```

this is the javascript code I used

```
var dateObj = str2date(Date_of_joining, "yyyy/mm/dd");
 var newDate = date2str(dateObj, "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

I even tried using Select Value step and changed the meta data to date and specified the format to "dd/MM/yyyy" but still not working.How do I solve this

[image: This is the error I got after using select value step]

Comment: you may reconstruct dateTime string

Comment: why do it in javascript? Just specify the right mask in your select values step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The date you are parsing is not using slashes, but you're defining slashes when you parse it.  Switch your slashes to dashes:

```
var dateObj = str2date(Date_of_joining, "yyyy-mm-dd");
var newDate = date2str(dateObj, "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function convertLinuxDate(linux_date) {
    //linux_date = "2001-01-02"
    var arrDate = linux_date.split("-");
    return arrDate[1] + "/" +arrDate[2] + "/" + arrDate[0];
}
//returns 01/02/2001
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

Try to reconstruct DateTime string as like this:

```
var dateObj = new Date(Date_of_joining);
var newDate = new Date(dateObj );
var formattedString = [newDate.Date(),newDate.Month()+1, newDate.getFullYear()].join("/");
alert(formattedString );
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: It threw an error : "cannot find function in Date in object Thus Apr 28 2016 11:39:11 GMT +0530(IST)."

Comment: @Deepesh I know where is  a bug, sorry I forget to write this : Date_of_joining

Comment: It's still giving the error :  "TypeError: Cannot find function Date in object Invalid Date(Script#3)"